# How to Change window frame border width in Google Chrome on Win 7

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome

I find the window height and width handles, i.e. the window frame border, too thin to easily capture them with my mouse.  Google Chrome v 81 as best I can tell is unaffected by the settings from Windows itself (in "personalize" in Win 7, but the dialog has been around for many versions).

So, my question is:

1. Can I change that from within Chrome, or by a command line switch?, or
2. Is there a way to tell Chrome to obey the parameters set in the Windows dialog?, or
3. Is that actually a feature of the skin I am using (Classic Blue Theme (back to 50))?

Thanks.

Comment: Try removing the skin to see if that fixes the problem. If it does then you need to modify the skin (which is off-topic for this site).

Comment: Thanks, but removing the skin had no effect.  Ultimately I am looking for a way to control this from OS settings, or failing that, from Chrome.  It's not clear to me what exactly about my question is on-topic, and what is off-topic?

Comment: Modifying the skin would have been off topic, but t's not the skin in this case, so it is still on topic.

Comment: I suspect that this is not doable, since I have found comments elsewhere that for some years, it has been hardwired into Chrome, and suggestions for modifying the theme (for other purposes) also do not work.  Probably, I need to pose this to the Chromium folks.

Answer (score 1):

[Check here for my comprehensive answer.](https://superuser.com/questions/1758977/how-to-change-border-width-in-ms-windows-to-grab-and-resize-it/1758981#1758981)